# Анимация нескольких фонов CSS

Tags: css, css-animation

```
.about {
    background: url('1.png'), url('2.png');
}
```

Могу ли я сделать анимацию. Т.е каждые 3 секунды менять фоны. С 1.png на 3.png, 2.png на 4.png

Comment: можешь.........

Comment: background можно подвигать, если Вас это устроит, а карттнки расположить плиткой

Answer (score 0):

Решил с помощью

```
animation: name 3s linear infinite; 
=>
@keyframes name {
 ...
}
```